# How to embed on-screen keyboard into gnome-screensaver 3.x unlock screen?

Tags: keyboard, gnome, screensaver, touchscreen, unlock

The *gconf* value `/apps/gnome-screensaver/embedded_keyboard_enable` in Oneiric no longer works obviously. Is there a way to show virtual keyboard in *gnome-screensaver* 3.x? Does similar *dconf* value exist?
It makes unlocking the screen without the keyboard on tablets impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Gnome.org](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeScreensaver/FrequentlyAskedQuestions) gives details of how to enable the embedded keyboard for a locked screen including the `gsettings` values

Any tablet-type screen keyboard must compy with the [XEmbed](http://standards.freedesktop.org/xembed-spec/latest/) specification.

Fortunately the standard *onboard* keyboard is XEmbed compliant - you need to pass the *--xid* parameter (type `onboard --help` for parameters you can pass to onboard)

Thus

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver embedded-keyboard-enabled true
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver embedded-keyboard-command "onboard --xid"
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The gnome-screensaver was updated to use the new [GSettings](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeGoals/GSettingsMigration) APIs instead of GConf. You can look through the list of options stored in GSettings by running `gsettings list-recursively | less` from a terminal, or by using the `dconf-editor` application.

The settings for `gnome-screensaver` have moved to the `org.gnome.desktop.screensaver` schema:

```
evan@caron:~$ gsettings list-recursively | grep org.gnome.desktop.screensaver
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver embedded-keyboard-command ''
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver embedded-keyboard-enabled false
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled true
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-delay uint32 0
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled true
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver logout-command ''
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver logout-delay uint32 7200
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver logout-enabled false
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver status-message-enabled true
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver user-switch-enabled true
```

So you can run `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver embedded-keyboard-enabled true` to enable the onscreen keyboard. You may also need to change the `embedded-keyboard-command` key.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Unfortunately, it didn't make keyboard work. But it was very useful information anyway and I'd rather split the bounty but I can't.