# Visual keyboard on lockscreen

Tags: 11.10, keyboard, lock-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable the on-screen keyboard in the unlock screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84050/how-do-i-disable-the-on-screen-keyboard-in-the-unlock-screen)

Recently, every time I'm on the lockscreen, the visual keayboard appears at the bottom of the screen. How do I get it to disappear, and not appear again?

Comment: The tricky part of this is that the visual keyboard is actually deactivated in the Accessibility settings. And it only appears on the lockscreen, and not on the login window, nor on the desktop...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably have been playing with the OnBoard keyboard with your screensaver and have enabled it to appear -

The solution would be the reverse of the linked Q&A - thus copy and paste the following into a terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver embedded-keyboard-enabled false
```

---

Linked Question:

1. [How to embed on-screen keyboard into gnome-screensaver 3.x unlock screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65059/how-to-embed-on-screen-keyboard-into-gnome-screensaver-3-x-unlock-screen/79589#79589)

Comment: Thanks, it disappeared! What I don't understand is that I never changed the screensaver preferences, nor the Accessibility ones...