# How do I enable onboard (on screen keyboard) on the lock-screen?

Tags: keyboard, lock-screen, onboard

I have a laptop-tablet device and I'm trying to enable onboard on the lock-screen.

Enabling onboard on the login screen is no problem but enabling the option

```
Show when unlocking the screen
```

is not giving the desired effect i.e. showing the keyboard on the lock-screen, when you lock your screen in a session.

Several questions exist that asks how to enable onboard on the lock-screen, however I have yet to find any that are actually referring to the lock-screen and not the login screen.

Is there any way to enable onboard on the lock-screen?

Edit:

This same question looks to be adressed here: [How to embed on-screen keyboard into gnome-screensaver 3.x unlock screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65059/how-to-embed-on-screen-keyboard-into-gnome-screensaver-3-x-unlock-screen) , however the options presented here do not give me an on screen keyboard on the lock-screen.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same issue. and no matter what I did I couldn't get it to work. So, on a whim I reinstalled Ubuntu from the latest version (14.10). I originally had 14.04 LTS. Nothing I did could get this to work (even reinstalling 14.04). So I downloaded the lastest release and did a clean install. And it looks as if the Devs fixed the issue in this latest release because now when I enable the option in Onboard settings, I get the keyboard pop up for logging in and from the lock screen. Hope this helps.

An additional note. When you enable the lock screen option you get prompted to enable Accessibility features. This is the key for log in screen. Onboard doesn't automatically pop up at login. But in the task bar, you'll see the little Accessibility icon (a little man figure in a circle). Touch that and you get the option to show the keyboard. This was also an issue with 14.04 LTS as it would never give me the accessibility icon in the task bar.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the answer! I have 14.04 running now. Thought I would stay with the LTS release, might reconsider that now. If it works for 14.10 there should be some library I could install to make it work. At least I know that it can work.